# unbindService inside custom button class

Tags: android, service

I have a problem to unbind a service

I created a class to custom a button. So this class extend Button class.

On this class, I bind my class with a remote service to update the button state.

```
    public class CustomButton extends Button implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Activity mActivity;

    public CustomButton(Context context) {
            super(context);
            init(context, null);
        }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (context instanceof Activity) {
                this.mActivity =  (Activity) context;


    Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, CustomService.class);

            final IRemoteCustomServiceCallback callback = new IRemoteCustomServiceCallback.Stub() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(boolean state) throws RemoteException {
                    Log.i("stateChanged", "New state is " + String.valueOf(state));
                    setAvailableMode(state);
                }

                @Override
                public IBinder asBinder() {
                    return this;
                }
            };

            ServiceConnection remoteConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
                @Override
                public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
                {
                    mService = IRemoteCustomService.Stub.asInterface(service);

                    try {
                        int test = mService.getPid();
                        Log.i("test", String.valueOf(test));

                        mService.registerCallback(callback);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                    try {
                        mService.unregisterCallback(callback);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mService = null;
                }
            };
            boolean state = mActivity.bindService(intent, remoteConnection, 0);
}
```

The problem is: when I close the application, I obtain a error: "[...] has leaked ServiceConnection [...] that was originally bound here"

I understand this error, but as I'm not receive the "signal" onStop or onDestroy, I can't unbind my service.

Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: do service binding/unbinding in your Activity/Fragment

Comment: Why don't you unbind service in `onPause` and bind it in `onResume` if unbind was successful?

Comment: Because I'm working on a library project and I add custom button into another application:

<mobile.test.com.library.Widget.CustomButton
        android:id="@+id/CustomButton"
        custom:state_avaibility="false"
        [...] />

And I bind my service directly by this custom button class. So I don't have onPause and onResume method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override method

```
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
}
```

use this method to unregister/unbind your remote service